# How to pass an array for column pattern matching in mapping dataflow derived column from CSV file through pipeline?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a mapping data flow with a derived column, where I want to use a column pattern for matching against an array of columns using in()

[image]

The data flow is executed in a pipeline, where I set the parameter $owColList_md5 based on a variable that I've populated from a single-line CSV file containing a comma-separated string

[image]

If I have a single column name in the CSV file/variable encapsuled in single quotes and have the "Expression" checkbox ticked, it works.
The problem is to get it to work with multiple columns. There seems to be parsing problems having multiple items in the variable each encapsuled in single-quotes, or potentially with the comma separating them. This often causes errors executing the data flow with messages like "store is not defined" etc

I've tried having ''col1'',''col2'' and "col1","col2" (2x single quotes and double quotes) in the CSV file. I've also tried having the file without quotes, trying to replace the comma with escaped quotes (using ) in the derived column pattern expression with no luck.

How do you populate this array in the derived column based on the data flow parameter which is based on the comma-separated string in the CSV file / variable from the pipeline with column names in a working way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While array types are not supported as data flow parameters, passing in a comma-separated string can work if you use the `instr()` function to match.

Say you have two columns, col1 and col2. Pass in a parameter with value '"col1","col2"'.

[image]

Then use `instr($<yourparamname>, '"' + name + '"') > 0` to see if the column name exists within the string you pass in. Note: You do not need double quotes, but the can be useful if you have column names that are subsets of other columns names such as id1 and id11.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is pretty much what I'm trying to do, but using the in() function instead. I pass the comma separated parameter wrapped in brackets in the column pattern expression to make it an array in the data flow, even though the parameter is of type string. Maybe your example can work differently only because it would take away the need of having single quotes in the parameter/dataflow expression.. will try